# how to sleep a thread in view class without disabling the touch on imageview?

Tags: android

how to sleep a thread in view class without disabling the touch on imageview?

**detailed description :**

I have an imageview having on touch listner.
and a View class having a TimerTask which on an event needs to be stopped for a second.

I used

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

but, this stops the touch listener too.

**EDIT:**
I tried a long for loop, It's still the same.

any alternative  or solution or suggestion appreciated?
thanks.

Comment: all the events are dispatched on the `MainThread` so you can not pause the `MainThread` for just a specific event like this. You should detail more your implementation and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: you can always use a delayed runnable